# Print Barcode in PDF with Django

Tags: django, pdf, barcode

I am using render_to_string in django for parse an HTML and export to PDF.

```
   html = render_to_string("etiquetaTNT.html", {
        'context': context,
        'barcode': b,
        'barcodeimg': barcodeimg,
    })

    font_config = FontConfiguration()
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, font_config=font_config)
    return response
```

I am trying to insert a barcode in PDF. I generate this barcode in a PNG.

```
    br = barcode.get('code128', b, writer=ImageWriter())
    filename = br.save(b)
    barcodeimg = filename
```

But the PDF in template, not show the image.

```
    <img class="logo" src="{{barcodeimg}}" alt="Barcode" />
```

I do not know the way to save the filename in the template that I want, and I do not know to show in the PDF, because any image is showed. For example, the logo, it is showed in HTML template but not in the PDF.

```
    <img class="logo" src="{{logo}}" alt="TNT Logo" />
```

The libraries that I am using:

```
   import barcode
   from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from django.template.loader import render_to_string

   from weasyprint import HTML
   from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration
```

I do not want to use Reportlab, because I need to render a HTML, not a Canvas.

Comment: What library are you using to print the pdf? Also, what library is generating the barcode?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Understanding the problem:

Think about what happens when you load a webpage. There is the initial request where the document is loaded, and then subsequent requests are made to fetch the images / other assets.

When you want to print some HTML to PDF using `weasyprint`, weasyprint has to fetch all of the other images. Checking out the `python-barcode` docs, `br.save(b)` is just going to return literally just the filename, (which will be saved in your current working directory). So your html will look something like this:

```
<img class="logo" src="some_filename.svg" alt="Barcode" />
```

Quite how it fetches this will depend on how you have `weasyprint` set up. You can check out `django-weasyprint` which has a custom URL fetcher. But as things stand,  weasyprint can't fetch this file.

#### A solution

There are a few ways you can fix this. But it depends alot on how you are deploying this. For example, heroku (as I understand it) doesn't have a local file system you can write to, so you would need to write the file to an external service like s3, and then insert the url for that into your template, which `weasyprint` will then be able to fetch. However, I think there is probably a simpler solution we can use in this case.

#### A better (maybe) Solution

Taking a look at the `python-barcode` docs it looks like you can write using SVG.
This is good because we can insert SVG straight into our HTML template (and avoid having to fetch any other assets). I would suggest something like the following

```
from io import BytesIO
from barcode.writer import SVGWriter

# Write the barcode to a binary stream
rv = BytesIO()
code = barcode.get('code128', b, writer=SVGWriter())
code.write(rv)

rv.seek(0)
# get rid of the first bit of boilerplate
rv.readline()
rv.readline()
rv.readline()
rv.readline()
# read the svg tag into a string
svg = rv.read()
```

Now you'll just need to insert that string into your template. Just add it to your context, and render it as follows:

```
{{svg}}
```

Comment: Your answer is brilliant, but I have a problem printing the svg, because it not print the barcode, only print a string:
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\xfa\x00\x00\x01\x18\x08\x02\x00\...

Comment: ah, sorry. I should have used the `SVGWriter` and not the `ImageWriter`. I have updated my answer, this should then render something which you can insert into your html :)

Comment: Only a last question, this generate an xml string. I checked the documentation but I do not find the way that it resolve an SVG string only.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas ah, I see what you mean. It looks like the first few lines generated are all the xml boilerplate. If you want just the svg tag bit by itself, we can read off the first 4 lines, and then read the rest of the content (just the svg bit) into our variable svg. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've updated it, I'm not sure the best way to read off the first 4 lines, but this will do. One way is to use readlines(), which will return an array, then you could slice and rejoin, but for this purpose, I think the above works fine.

Comment: Yes, it work. Cut the lines and resolve svg tags. Now I have to clean the string and get the svg tags, but it is easy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: :) Glad to have helped

Comment: I had to use `mark_safe(rv.getvalue().decode())`, to get the barcode to appear in the HTML correcly, I had to use https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/75#issuecomment-267452666 to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the solution provided by @tim-mccurrach, I have created a templatetag for it.

**/app/templatetags/barcode_tags.py**

```
from django import template

from io import BytesIO
import barcode

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def barcode_generate(uid):
    rv = BytesIO()
    # code = barcode.get('code128', b, writer=SVGWriter())
    code = barcode.get('code128', uid, 
    writer=barcode.writer.SVGWriter())
    code.write(rv)

    rv.seek(0)
    # get rid of the first bit of boilerplate
    rv.readline()
    rv.readline()
    rv.readline()
    rv.readline()
    # read the svg tag into a string
    svg = rv.read()
    return svg.decode("utf-8")
```

And then In the template.html:

```
{% load barcode_tags %}
{% barcode_generate object.uid as barcode_svg %}
{{barcode_svg | safe}}
```